# Are you meant to compile the description types with TypeScript too?

Tags: typescript

I am sure this is a stupid question and the answer is **yes**, but I originally thought that when I was using the Definitely Typed descriptors for existing frameworks I would only be using them for compilation type safety and intellisense style lookups while coding.

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/knockout (for example)

Now im not using Visual Studio, im just using Rubymine and calling tsc.exe in my rake build script, however I just noticed that when I am converting my source files it is keeping the types such as `KnockoutObservableString` whereas I assumed by magic it would replace that with `ko.observable`.

So should I be converting all descriptors too and including them in with the source code on the webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no.

Long answer: you do **not** need to compile definition files. If you'd look at one, you'll notice they contain only interfaces, hence should you be able to compile one it would result in an empty JavaScript file.

The definition files are used to add typing support to existing JavaScript libraries, without having to translate the library itself to TypeScript.

Writing the following line in TypeScript:

```
var myObservableString: KnockoutObservableString;
```

would be compiled to

```
var myObservableString;
```

The point of these types is that at compile time you will be notified if you've made errors. For example:

```
myObservableString = ko.observable("Hello World"); // valid
myObservableString = ko.observable(false); // error, because you have specified the variable as an observable string
```

However you still need to instantiate the observable in TypeScript, you can't call `new KnockoutObservableString(string);`

You should never ever get these types in your compiled JavaScript, so you're probably encountering another problem here. Are you referring to the output of compiling the definition files?